# Theoretical Upper Bound on Processor Speed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, speed-of-light, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, computer

Barring aside considerations such as heat dissipation, capacitance, etc... (aka any sort of technological issue) what is the fastest speed of a processor?

I am told that at distances of 1 planck length  $L =1.616$ x $ 10^{-35}$ m

Heisenberg's uncertainty principle hovers around an error factor of 1.

Does that suggest then CPU speeds (in this case measured via period) theoretically cannot exceed something along the same order of magnitude of:

$L/c = 5.387$ x $10^{42}$  calculations per second? (pretending a single cycle of a lightwave bouncing across a single planck length of distance amounts to an entire calculation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Seth Lloyd's [Ultimate physical limits to computation](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9908043), the time taken for an operation is limited by the uncertainty in the energy available $\Delta t=\pi\hbar/2E$

Comment: That whole paper is great.  I refer to it quite regularly.  The paper does address this question completely.